# Vue Component Import

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I know this question has been asked several times, unfortunately i can't figure it out. My question is how to import all vue single file components from a directory in one shot. Le'me clear that..

Say i have directory named as `Add/Items` where i stored all vue components, `ItemA`, `ItemB` and so on. I want to import these components to a `Add.vue` file which is sitting just outside the `Add` directory.

I have tried these methods (in `Add.vue` file script section) ..
Method #1:

```
import ItemA from './Add/Items/ItemA'
import ItemB from './Add/Items/ItemB'

export default {
  components: {
   'item-a': ItemA,
   'item-b': ItemB
  }
}
```

and it works, with `<item-a/>` as well as with `<component is="item-a"/>`

but the following method does not work.

Method #2

Here i have created a file named `index.js` at `Add/Items` directory where the following snippet is written

```
import itemA from './ItemA'
import ItemB from './ItemB'

export default {
  ItemA,
  ItemB
}
```

and in the `Add.vue` file

```
import items from './Add/Items'

export default {
  components: {
    items
  }
}
```

And it is working neither with `<item-a/>` nor with `<component is="item-a"/>`.
Is there something i m missing ?? and by the way, `<component :is="item-a"/>` is my preference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In last example(`Add.vue`) in your question you will get this(that is not what you want):

```
  components: {
    items: {
      ItemA,
      ItemB
    }
  }
```

You just need to use spread(`...`) operator or assign items to `components` directly:

```
export default {
  components: {
    ...items
  }
}
```

OR this:

```
export default {
  components: items
}
```